Is there open source scanner software compatible with Motorola 9190, or an SDK to roll my own?
TLDR: Customer wants to use Motorola 9190, but it doesn't have Datawedge installed, and Datawedge isn't free. Where can I find an open source app to read from the scanner, and push it out (preferably over a REST API)?
Absent that, is there an SDK to write my own, or a different, more modern scanner that would be easier to integrate?
Details:
I'm working on an inventory application. The application is a C# .NET WinForm app that compares counted inventory against expected inventory (exported from Point of Sale - POS - system), and generates a report.
I have the application working with a cheaper scanner that interfaces with the laptop by acting like a keyboard (input, once transferred, is simply 'typed' into whatever control has focus).
The customer wants to use multiple scanners and I suspect that won't work with these scanners (TBD), but they also provided me with a used Motorlola 9190 scanner running Windows Mobile 5.0 for testing.
The scanner's manual indicates that it is supposed to have an application called DataWedge installed on it, which (high level understanding here) is able control the scanner, read input, and output it (haven't read details, I'm guessing - hoping? - a web request).
Problem is, it doesn't have that application installed, and Datawedge is neither free nor open source.
So, is there a different application I can use? If not, is there an SDK to roll my own (the Zebra EMDK, I think? Is that free?) Is there a different scanner someone that spends more time in this space more can recommend?
